# error: 403 Forbidden in centos 6.4 for php website

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos6

After configuring my website in Centos 6.4. 
When i hit the url in browser I'm getting 403 Forbidden. 
My apache, php and mysql is fine. 
When set to default DocumentRoot in httpd.conf my test page will open properly. 
But when i change DocumentRoot to my project's www folder it says 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `httpd` user has the read/execute priviledge to the project's www folder.

you can try to do this

```
chmod -R 755 project_www_folder
```

and reload your browser

====== add segment to apache config file ======

```
<Directory "/path to project folder/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: [root@vishapp ~]# cd /root/myproject/www
[root@vishapp www]# ls -l
total 56
drwxrwxrwx.  7 apache apache 4096 Apr 24 12:12 administrator
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache 4096 Apr 24 12:12 components
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 1461 Apr 24 12:12 configuration.php
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   46 Apr 24 12:12 images -> ../vendor/anahita/anahita/vendor/joomla/images
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   43 Apr 24 12:12 includes -> ../vendor/anahita/anahita/src/site/includes
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache  577 Apr 25  2014 index.php
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache 4096 Apr 24 12:12 modules

Comment: thanks for reply Xing. Httpd user apache has all rights. But still getting 403 forbidden

Comment: the apache user must have the privilidge to the parent folder of index.php. if already have, check the apache's log file for more infomation.

Comment: yeah he is having privilege to all the folder and subfolder inside my project folder. Still same issue

Comment: 10.156.1.150 - - [25/Apr/2014:07:48:38 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 289 "-" "check_http/v1.5 (nagios-plugins 1.5)"

Comment: I have lots of this line in my access log file

Comment: try add this segment to your apache config file. <Directory "/path to project folder/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: I added that code snippet to my httpd.conf file with my project's  www folder. Still same.

Comment: restart your apache, and try. if still have this problem, I can't help you.

Comment: i did restart my apache everytime i made changes to httpd.conf file Xing. Thanks for your time.